# Heroku sbt play console is SLOW

Tags: scala, heroku, playframework-2.0, sbt

Hi I run play framework 2.1 RC1 (but this apply to sbt) on heroku with 1 web dyno.

I frequently want to access scala REPL with the command `heroku run sbt play console` to make some operations.

Everything works just fine but it takes about 10 minutes to go from command to REPL.
Eveything is compiling 10 times slower than when I deploy.

Is there any work around to go to the REPL in heroku faster? Or initiate a REPL instance and then attach to it?

Answer (score 2):

I was using Play 2.1.1 on Heroku and was also suffering from very long build times. Quite often the deployment was aborted (Slug compilation is currently limited to 15 minutes).

It turned out that sbt 0.12.3 which I was using that time was quite slow (memory issues). Most of those issues have been fixed in sbt 0.12.4 which is much faster. Unfortunately, Heroku officially only has support right now for SBT 0.11.0 - 0.12.3.

However, by changing the buildpack URL as follows, you can build with sbt 0.12.4:

`$ heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-scala.git#sbt-0.12.4`

Answer (score 1):

You are launching a remote service and with only 1 dyno (Which means that after 1 hour it goes to "sleep", and it wakes up it has to cold-start the dyno). Of course it is slow.

Granted, 10 minutes it's a bit too much (unless you have a massive project, slow connection, or some other external factor (like issues in the platform itself).

Anyway, only Heroku may be able to solve that, you should open a support ticket with them.

Comment: thank you for your comment. well heroku is fast and deploy time is fine. I can't see a reason why "sleep" to be a problem to this issue.

project is relative small. 4.000 lines of scala code. But since deploy time is small why going to REPL does x10 compile time. 

It seems to be platform issue. I will check it with heroku.